# Which platforms can Sing# be used to develop for?

Tags: platform

I was just reading about [Singularity](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/singularity/) and one of its development languages, Sing#. Now I want to know which platforms I can develop for with Sing#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sing# is a derivative of C# that they made specifically to develop Singularity. I imagine it's just a specialized form for making an OS

http://www.microsoft-watch.com/content/operating_systems/microsofts_other_os.html

Answer (score 1):

I would image its proprietary to Singularity.

There is also Spec# which Sing# is derived from ([from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sing_Sharp)).

Answer (score 1):

I believe Sing# was developed specifically for and only runs under Singularity, unfortunately.